# Magento: Add additional info to Invoice PDF

Tags: magento, m2e-pro

I am utilizing M2EPro to sync orders from eBay and Amazon.

I would like to add the Amazon Order ID and Ebay Order ID to my PDF invoices.

I need the data from:

```
Column amazon_order_id from m2epro_ebay_order
```

and

```
Column ebay_order_id from m2epro_amazon_order
```

Can anyone offer suggestions as to a protected function to add to Abstract.php or any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the help! I used:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(entity_id); 
$paymentInfo = Mage::helper('payment')->getInfoBlock($order->getPayment()) 
->setIsSecureMode(true);

$channelOrderId = $paymentInfo->getChannelOrderId();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create models for the tables (if there aren't any available already)
[How to create a model](http://codemagento.com/2011/02/creating-and-instantiating-a-model/)
Then you can simply get an instance of the model

```
$ebay = Mage::getModel('m2epro/ebay')->load($row_id);
echo $ebay->getData('ebay_order_id');
```